# A boy has $3$ library tickets and 8 books of his interest in the library.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> A boy has $3$ library tickets and 8 books of his interest in the library.Of these $8$,he doesn't want to borrow Chemistry part $2$ unless
>   Chemistry part $1$ is also borrowed.In how many ways can he choose $3$ books to be borrowed?

I did this question by taking cases 

1)Both chemistry books aren't borrowed

2)Chemistry $1$ is borrowed

So,for first case $C(6,3)$ and

second $C(6,1)$ because he will be left with only one choice.

But it's answer is $C(7,2)+C(6,3)$

Comment: I suspect the intended answer is $C(7,2)+C(6,3)$, where $C(7,2)$ is the number of ways of choosing two books in addition to *Chemistry 1*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem is in interpretation of second case**

I think problem caused here is due to misinterpretation of this statement  "*he doesn't want to borrow Chemistry part $2$ unless
Chemistry part $1$ is also borrowed*".

This statement implies that he can borrow Chemistry $2$ only when he had borrowed Chemistry $1$.But,he is not strictly bounded to borrow
Chemistry part $2$ with $1$.He can borrow  any two books from 7 books."Statement in your textbook states that he **"can"** but you had interrupted
as he **have to buy both books together** .
         OR

**$C(7,2)+C(6,3)$**